# Combining corresponding data in Excel worksheets

Tags: excel

I have multiple Excel workbooks that each have the same worksheets with the same headers, simply different data by header per worksheet. I want to take each of these workbooks and have Excel put them into a new workbook that has the same worksheets only each worksheet consolidates the data from the other ones.

The combine and load feature does exactly what I need, but it seems to me that it only does it for a single worksheet and not for all of them simultaneously. Is there a method that does so in a simultaneous matter?

EDIT: To further clarify, let's say I have two spreadsheets, spreadsheet 1 and 2, each containing the same three tabs: daily totals, weekly totals and monthly totals. I want to be able to combine both spreadsheets into a single spreadsheet which contains the same tabs, but aggregated where daily totals from spreadsheet 1 is stacked on top of daily totals from spreadsheet 2 and so on.

Comment: Can you define the : _".. each worksheet consolidates the data from the other ones."_ part ? some sample data/table may be useful..

Comment: @p._phidot_ Absolutely. I added an edit to the OP. Thank you!

Comment: so.. in the weekly totals and monthly totals tab.. there is gap in between (to cater for 7 days.. = 1 weekly total, 4 weeks = 1 monthly totals) ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ Yes, that's right